# How to delete a substring from a string starting with a starting point until the end?

Tags: c#, string, split

IMG354-62850003215 
I want to trim this starting from "-" until the end
So the output should be IMG354

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: If you typed your three tags into google I'm pretty sure you would have found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"IMG354-62850003215".Split('-')[0];
```

It will return:

```
IMG354
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "IMG354-62850003215";
int index = s.IndexOf('-');
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, index)); // IMG354
```

or you can [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) your string like;

```
string s = "IMG354-62850003215";
Console.WriteLine(s.Split('-')[0]); // IMG354
```

But next time, please use Google first. You can find tons of information about this kind of string operations which probably only takes 30 seconds. And probably take less time asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
string name = "IMG354-62850003215";
int found = name.IndexOf("-");

name = name.Remove(found, name.Length-found);
```

Comment: Upvote? o.O This will throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. There is no lengt as `name.Length` after `found + 1` index. After your edit: Still throws exception. There is no length `name.Length-found` after your `found + 1`.

Comment: No, still wrong. `found + 1` should be simply `found`, also that is not enough. `found` can be `-1` if char is not found, in that case you'll again get `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`